# java.lang.NullPointerException when Zypher is publishing report to JIRA

Tags: jenkins, testng, reportng, jira-zephyr

I use a reportng format to publish the report to the Jira, but I am seeing the nullpointer exception:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.thed.zephyr.jenkins.utils.rest.TestCaseUtil.executeTests(TestCaseUtil.java:424)
> at com.thed.zephyr.jenkins.utils.rest.TestCaseUtil.processTestCaseDetails(TestCaseUtil.java:564)
> at com.thed.zephyr.jenkins.reporter.ZfjReporter.perform(ZfjReporter.java:99)
> at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
> at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
> at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
> at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
> at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
> Build step 'Publish test result to Zephyr for JIRA' marked build as failure
> Finished: FAILURE
> ```

Do you know why? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an ongoing issue in the [Jenkins community](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43884). You can subscribe to their JIRA feed for further updates.